# How to Format Timer Style Text in SwiftUI with Leading Zeros?

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently working on a SwiftUI project and I'm using the .timer style with a Text view to display a time duration. However, I'm having trouble formatting it to include leading zeros for hours, minutes, and seconds.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
       
        let components = DateComponents(hour: 2, minute: 15, second: 12)
        let futureDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: Date())!

        Text(futureDate, style: .timer)
            .font(.title)
            .frame(width: 120)
    }
}
```

The output I get is: 2:15:12, but I would like it to be: 02:15:12.

Could anyone please help me with the appropriate SwiftUI code to achieve this formatting with the .timer style? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

As a follow-up, I have reviewed the documentation provided at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/displaying-dynamic-dates but unfortunately,

Comment: You can’t change .timer you can create your own formatted but you can’t change the style

Comment: Thank you for the information. I tried with Timer, but I wasn't successful, and I believe there might be certain limitations with Widget Extension

Comment: Timer doesn’t work either watch the news widget videos from WWDC23

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to use `.timer` style I don't think there is direct way to customize its formatting, as the `.timer` style in SwiftUI takes care of the countdown for you. But you can easily achieve same thing using `Timer` publisher and adjusting `DateFormatter` as you need

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var time = Date()
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(dateFormatter.string(from: time))
            .font(.title)
            .frame(width: 120)
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                time = Date()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested it with Playground, and it works. However, when I create a new project with Xcode 15.0 and test it with a widget extension, the Timer doesn't start.

Comment: I guess it's because widgets aren't designed for real time update like in an app. In our case we update our view every second with timer publisher. Widgets in iOS use a TimelineProvider to determine when they should be updated.

Comment: Thanks. WidgetKit doesn't allow updating the timeline every second. In this case, is there no way to achieve the format I want with leading zeros?